# Android: How to get Google Play app rating per country?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

Now, the app rating displayed to the users is function of their country/device/etc... But it seems that there is a kind of 'default rating' per country. I would like to get the default app rating displayed in Google Play for my app for every country. I would like to get this rating for all countries easily.

I didn't find a way to do that easily in Google Play Console ? Is there a menu or button I didn't see ? Or any trick ? Or any API ?

Thanks.